# Android emojis: how to change theme?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

The yellow blob emojis on my android 6 phone are mostly incomprehensible. Is that one laughing or looking sad? No idea.

Is there a way to replace them with pictures that better represent the emotions they're supposed to help us communicate?

AFAIK emoji are sent as Unicode code points, so presumably they're rendered like a font would be.

(I feel very old asking this question, like I'm just supposed to know... it might even help if there was a list describing the picture in words)

Comment:  This emoji, as seen on android, confuses me. It's crying/laughing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unicode character codes found here to choose an emojis you like better:

http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Comment: Thanks so much! I find most of the faces very confusing, even now I know what they're supposed to look like! But looks like on android you're always stuck with the same set?